# Problema responsive nav

Tags: html, css, responsive, flexbox

Que tal comunidad? Espero que esten bien, aca un novato jugando un poco con html y css, estoy teniendo problemas al querer hacer un menu responsive con flexbox, al achicar la pantalla llega un punto en el que se desbordan los elementos de mi nav y no entiendo como puedo solucionar eso. Ademas cree un div para practicar un poco animaciones y su contenido tambien se desborda. De que manera puedo posicionar ese elemento div en la parte inferior izquierda de la pantalla? Mi intencion es de a poco ir entendiendo los conceptos y poder hacer un menu responsive que al achicar la resolucion se vuelva del tipo "hamburguesa" Todo consejo es bienvenido para aprender

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;


}

.titulosnav{
  margin: 9%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;



}

body{
   background: gray;


}



  header {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction:row;
    background: white;


}

nav{
  display: flex;
  width: 38%;
  margin-left: 23%;



}


.ayuda{
  width: 6%;
  margin: 1%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  border-radius: 9px;
  background: white;
  transition: width 0.8s;
   animation: spinner 2s linear infinite;

}


h1{
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: #F05E23;
  margin: 3%;
  font-size: 18px;


}



div:hover{
   display: flex;
   width: 30%;
   transition: width 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.5,-0.5,0.5,1.5);
   color: #F05E23;

}

 .titulosnav:hover{
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #F05E23;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  transition: color 0.3s;
  -webkit-animation: bounce 1.3s ease infinite alternate;
  word-wrap: break-word;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head></head>

  <body>

<header>

  <nav>
    <a class="titulosnav" href="#">Novedades</a>
    <a class="titulosnav" href="#">Deportes</a>
    <a class="titulosnav" href="#">Espectaculos</a>
    <a class="titulosnav" href="#">Moda</a>
    <a class="titulosnav" href="#">Humor</a>


  </nav>



</header>

  <div class="ayuda">

<h1>Que?</h1>



  </div>



</body>
</html>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

si buscas una solución rápida para auto-ajustar tu barra de navegación, esta la opción de bootstrap, lo que hice fue utilizar bootstrap 4, ya te incluye su propio estilo de css.

Espero y te sirva de algo.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">

        <!-- Links -->
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Novedades</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Deportes</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Espectaculos</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Moda</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Humor</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <br>
    
    <div class="container">
        <h3>Navbar With Dropdown</h3>
        <p>This example adds a dropdown menu in the navbar.</p>
    </div>

</body>
```